# JQuery event handlers not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please look my code -

**Html**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" style="padding-top:10px;">Body :<br><br>
       <a id="expand" href="javascript:;">expand</a>
    </td>
    <td>
       <textarea rows="6" cols="30" required="required" id="message" name="message">
        </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**jquery**

```
$(function(){
       $("#expand").click(function(){                      
               $('#message').animate({"height": "300px"}, "slow" );
               $(this).attr('id','colaspe').html('colaspe');
               return false;
        });
        $("#colaspe").click(function(){
               $('#message').animate({"height": "80px"}, "slow" );
               $(this).attr('id','expand').html('expand');
               return false;
        });
});
```

My above code working when click on `expand`. But `colaspe` not working.

#### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chinmay235/2ornbh0w/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#expand',function(){                      
    $('#message').animate({"height": "300px"}, "slow" );
    $(this).attr('id','colaspe').html('colaspe');
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click','#colaspe',function(){
   $('#message').animate({"height": "80px"}, "slow" );
   $(this).attr('id','expand').html('expand');
   return false;
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/857L5hwj/)**

**Reason:** You are changing the attributes and properties dynamically. For such elements there is `.on` function to bind the events with element in jQuery. So you need to use the `.on` function with element.

Comment: @chatfun My pleasure to help you. :) +1 for you.

Answer (score 5):

The `#colaspe` button is not there when you try to add the event handler. Either create both of the buttons at the same time or use the delegate pattern for handling the clicks.

https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3):

It's not safe to always change the id. Try using a **class** instead.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="padding-top:10px;">Body :<br><br>
            <a id="control" href="javascript:;" class="expand">expand</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea rows="6" cols="30" required="required" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
$("#control").click(function(){   
    if ($(this).hasClass('expand')) {
        $('#message').animate({"height": "300px"}, "slow" );
        $(this).removeClass('expand').addClass('colapse').html('colapse');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('colapse')) {
        $('#message').animate({"height": "80px"}, "slow" );
        $(this).removeClass('colapse').addClass('expand').html('expand');
    }

    return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

it happens as id is not there when you apply event

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#expand', function () {
    $('#message').animate({
        "height": "300px"
    }, "slow");
    $(this).attr('id', 'colaspe').html('colaspe');
    return false;
});
$(document.body).on("click", '#colaspe', function () {
    $('#message').animate({
        "height": "80px"
    }, "slow");
    $(this).attr('id', 'expand').html('expand');
    return false;
});
```

user [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/2ornbh0w/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the current button id which doesn't work.

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') === 'expand'){
        $('#message').animate({"height": "300px"}, "slow" );
        $(this).attr('class','colaspe').html('colaspe');
    } 
    else {
               $('#message').animate({"height": "80px"}, "slow" );
               $(this).attr('class','expand').html('expand');
    }
});
```

Look at [this fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ornbh0w/6/)