# jquery create and delete input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
</head>


<body>

    <button id="add_field">Noch ein Inputfeld</button>
    <hr>
    <div class="input_fields">


    </div>


    <script>
        $(function(){

            var number = 1;

            $("#add_field").click(function(){
                if(number < 11){
                    var name = "input";
                    name = name + number;
                    $(".input_fields").append('<a>'+ number +':</a><input type="text" name="' + name + '" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">entfernen</a><br>');
                    number++;
                }
                else{
                    alert("10 ist Max");    
                }
            });

            $(".remove_field").click(function(){
                $(this).parent('input').remove();
                x--;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I can create input fields, but if i press on the **loeschen** Button, nothing happens. So i think here is a mistake in this function:

```
$(".remove_field").click(function(){
    $(this).parent('input').remove();
    x--;
});
```

Comment: Input is not a parent to that element but a sibling. What output do you want on click of remove? Also you would need event delegation to bind click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('.input_fields').on('click', '.remove_field', function(){
    $(this).parent('input').remove();
    x--;
});
```

You need to use the delegate pattern for the event handler.

You might also be interested in:

[Your fiddle fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/1gcwn4ve/2/) (note that you need to re-do the logic for displaying numbers if you want them to handle inputs getting removed from the middle)

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

[JQuery event handlers not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29692148/1630906)

https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events to dynamically added elements:

```
$("body").on("click",".remove_field",function(){
  $(this).parent('input').remove();
  number--;
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/umd67Lap/)**

Comment: Look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gcwn4ve/). I did it with your code, but nothing happens.

Comment: @Name, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30017665/1630906) for an updated version of your fiddle.

Comment: @Name: it did not worked because x is not defined. declare it globally.